# How to slave the Honeywell Tuxedo Touch to OpenHAB?

Tags: security, alarms, home-automation, openhab, z-wave

I have the Honeywell Tuxedo Touch and it supports Z-Wave technology. How can I slave the Tuxedo alarm panel to OpenHAB (also supports Z-Wave) running on Raspberry Pi? Or do I need to slave OpenHAB to the Tuxedo? What hardware would be needed to do such a setup?

Is this even possible? If not what alarm system would be best for use with OpenHAB?

I would really prefer to make OpenHAB the master because of all the programming and rule capabilities of programming my own system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I discovered that the Honeywell Tuxedo Touch is not an alarm panel, it is just a fancy touch keypad. The alarm panel is the Honeywell Vista 21iP alarm panel or something of that nature.

The Tuxedo does support Z-Wave and it does have home-automation, but if I'm going to use OpenHAB running on Raspberry Pi then the key is to setup the Tuxedo as a secondary controller to the Raspberry Pi. Any changes made to states such as light switches made through the Tuxedo would automatically be propagated through the Z-Wave network to the OpenHAB and notifications would be sent to the phone from there.

But getting the alarm panel to connect to OpenHAB now requires a little keypad interface system with an Ethernet port on it that is a little circuit board made by a company Eyez-On. http://www.eyezon.com

The circuit board is EnvisaLink3. http://www.eyezon.com/?page_id=176

There is a group at OpenHAB that is working on writing a plugin module for OpenHAB that will interface with the EnvisaLink3 so that the two can talk together via a standard Ethernet network.

In this way the OpenHAB system would be the monitoring service and Eyez-On would report any alarm status updates to the OpenHAB. OpenHAB would then be responsible for forwarding messages or making calls or sending text messages or e-mails. You could self monitor this way and still likely get your Home Insurance discount for having a monitored alarm system, but without paying the monthly fee.